# Jasmine - How to spy on a function call within a function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

The following is in my controller:

```
$scope.addRangesAndSquare = function() {
    $scope.addLeftRange();
    $scope.addCenterSquare();
    $scope.addRightRange();
}
```

And I want to spy on `$scope.addLeftRange()`, so that when `$scope.addRangesAndSquare` is called so is `$scope.addLeftRange()`:

```
it('expect addLeftRange to be called after calling addRangesAndSquare', function () {
    spyOn(scope ,'addRangesAndSquare');
    spyOn(scope, 'addLeftRange');
    scope.addRangesAndSquare();
    expect(scope.addLeftRange).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

By default, when you use `spyOn` with **jasmine**, it mocks that function and doesn't actually execute anything within it. If you want to test further function calls within, you'll need to call `.andCallThrough()`, like so:

```
spyOn($scope, 'addRangesAndSquare').andCallThrough();
```

that should do it.

Comment: Thanks. Also, I had to comment out or add a spy to the other two inner functions, otherwise it will throw out an error.

Comment: In Jasmine 2, it has been changed to `spyOn($scope, 'addRangesAndSquare').and.callThrough();`