# Jasmine mocking a constructor within a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-scope, jasmine

I get an error when running Jasmine tests: 'ReferenceError: JSZip is not defined'. Here's my controller:

```
$scope.makeZip = function() {
    var zip = new JSZip();
    zip.file('myPhoto.txt', 'Hello World);
    return 'foo' + zip.generate();
};
```

And test:

```
it('should make a zip with correct name', function() {
    var zipFileName = scope.makeZip();
    expect(zipFileName).toMatch('foo');
});
```

My guess is that I need to mock JSZip constructor somehow: I tried inserting the following at the beginning of the test:

```
spyOn(window, 'JSZip').andReturn(null);
```

but then I get 'JSZip() method does not exist'.
I thought this is similar problem to [Jasmine - How to spy on a function call within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705121/jasmine-how-to-spy-on-a-function-call-within-a-function), but I couldn't find a right way to fix the issue.

Any ideas? Thanks for all help!

Comment: Could you show the function for 'makePhotos()'? I only see "makeZip"

Comment: silly me, names fixed now

Comment: Haha, it happens. So, everything is working as expected, then?

Comment: no, the problem is still there unfortunately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! I didn't actually want to test JSZip, only to check whether a function makeZip is called correctly.

```
it('should make a zip with correct name', function() {
    window.JSZip = function() {
            this.file = function() {};
            this.generate = function() {
                return 'bar';
            };
        };
        var zipFileName = scope.makeZip();
        expect(zipFileName).toMatch('foo'); //makeZip should return string containing 'foo'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JSZip is defined on the window. You should not have to pass it into the constructor. In your jasmine page (where you holster your specs), **reference jszip.js**. If you want, you could create a service..

*your angular module*.value("JSZip",JSZip);

then pass it into your controller. This is only useful if you wanted to mock JSZip, though.