# Mocking other module within tested function

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a unit test for my `testService`. I call a function `create` which calls another subfunction `save` which mirrors (`apiService.send`) the data to a national server. In my unit test I don't want to test the connection to a server etc. so I want to mock the function `apiService.send` and instead always return a certain value. But I still want to keep the rest of the save function, because I really want to check if everything was saved well in the database.

As far as I read [Jasmine - How to spy on a function call within a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705121/jasmine-how-to-spy-on-a-function-call-within-a-function) this can be achieved with and.callThrough

### test

```
testService.createTest(appUser, testData, (err, test) ->
  expect(err).toBe(null)
  ...
```

### function

```
saveTest = (test, method, appUserToken, callback) ->
  async.parallel
    local: (next)->
      test.save((err) ->
        return next err if err?
        return next null, test._id
      )
    national: (next)->
      apiService.send(environment, method, test, appUserToken, (err, testId) ->
        return next err if err?
        TestModel.update({_id: test._id},  { $set: { refId: new Object(testId) }}, (err, result) ->
          return next err if err?
          return next 'Referenz Id wurde nicht gespeichert' if result.nModified==0
          return next null, test._id
        )
      )
    (err, results)->
      return callback err if err?
      return callback null, results.local


exports.createTest = (appUser, testData, callback) ->
  ...
  saveTest(newTest, 'createTest', appUser.token, callback)
```

Comment: Searched for the wrong term, I guess this looks like what I was looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747035/how-to-unit-test-a-node-js-module-that-requires-other-modules
I will post a solution as soon as I get it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module proxyquire (https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) can be used to achieve the solution:

```
proxyquire =  require('proxyquire').noCallThru()
apiServiceStub = {}
```

Require your original module through proxyquire. For the module you want to overwrite is important to use the same path as in your original module. In this case: `../api/api.service.js`

```
testService = proxyquire(applicationDir + 'backend/test/test.service.js', '../api/api.service.js': apiServiceStub)
```

Write a fake function

```
apiServiceStub.send = (environment, method, data, token, callback) ->
  console.log "I'm a fake function"
  return callback null, testDummies.SUPERADMIN_ID
```